# Delete duplicate records with joined table and fix foreign keys on related table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

We had these tables:
Users
Addresses -> User have address_Id
Posts -> post has user_id

The issue is that the Users table had many duplicates exactly the same records, all fields are equal, and also in some cases the addresses are the same, so we joined the Users and Addresses tables to compare each field
And then update the foreign keys in the posts table with one of the duplicates rows.
Then remove all duplicates from the Users.
We used an sql solution, something like this http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2004/10/07/2190.aspx but a little longer.

My questions is how to do the same task with linq and entity frame work?
While searching for this issue in sql I found many talking about it, but couldn't find something about doing it with linq or entity framework, so if someone faced this before or have a starting point this will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ListUsers = from user in context.Users
            join address in context.Addresses
            select new
            {
                User = user,
                Address = address
            } into users
            group users by new 
            {
                user.Property1OtherthanID,
                user.Property2OtherthanID,
                ...
                address.Property1OtherthanID,
                address.Property2OtherthanID,
                ...
            } into distinct
            select new
            {
                FirstUserID = distinct.FirstOrDefault().User.ID,
                UserIDs = distinct.Select(u => u.User.ID)
            }
```

This will give you a list of all the `UserIDs` with same records and addresses and `FirstUserID` as Key.

You can then check for each `UserID` in `ListUsers` if `Posts` contains that foreign key, if yes replace it with `ListUsersItem.FirstUserID`.

And for removing all duplicates from the Users, do the same with `Users` and if it matches with `UserIDs` and is not `FirstUserID` delete it. Or you can use the `Distinct()` method with using another method as Comparer to compare all the properties before distincting them.